# slow performance or misconfiguration

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I have several controllers. Each one makes requests to the database. Everything works perfectly, but the responses are too slow.

I thought it was because of the Laravel configuration with respect to the database data, but then try a controller like this:

```
     Route::get('foo', function () {
         return 'Hello World';
      });
```

It's just a test, which returns hello world, something very basic, and when I test it locally, the response takes 300/400ms and in production it takes 1200ms, equivalent to 1sec and a little more.

What causes this to happen?

Comment: Which web server are you using? Let's start with that.

Comment: Pretty sure there is more to this than what looks on the surface.

Comment: I use Wamp server 2.5, with apache 2.4.9, php 5.5.12 and mysql 5.6.17.. the server is virtual and has Windows Server 2012R2..

Comment: Why Windows? Most web servers are Linux, and for a very good reason. I assume you do this because you use Wamp? Anyway, this information doesn't tell us anything about the web server itself. Does it have 1 CPU at 1Mhz or 6 CPUs at 3Mhz? 4GB of RAM or 16GB? It being "virtual" doesn't sound hopeful.

Comment: that is normal value for laravel , but you can increase those values,use cache or use distribute systems for more speed

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty difficult to pinpoint the source of the error, but since it appears to be slow in production too, I think you need to set up a new Laravel project and compare its speed with your current project. It
could be that your Laravel dependencies were not set up properly during your project's initialization but if you happened to pass the test, I think you should take a careful look at the server you are using and what may be limiting its functionality.